# Existence of $f$ with $\partial^{N+1}f(x) > C\sum_{k=1}^{N}\sup|\partial^{k} f|$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, distribution-theory

> Given $N\in \mathbb Z_{\geq0}$, $0<C$, $x\in \mathbb R$, does there exist a compact support $f\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb R)$ such that $\partial^{N+1}f(x) > C\sum_{k=1}^{N}\sup|\partial^{k} f|$ ?

In general I think it might exist since the criterion doesn't seem that strict to me, can assume $x=0$ to simplify, I tried something like $f=\int\cdots\int g$ then $g = \partial^{N+1}f$ but I don't know how to construct $g$.

Comment: One idea: If you have one $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$ and define $f_\epsilon(x) = f(x/\epsilon)$, how does $\partial^k f_\epsilon$ change with $\epsilon$?

Comment: @md2perpe  it converges to $\partial^k f$ as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+$?

Comment: Don't just guess; your guess is wrong. Compute it!

Comment: @md2perpe my bad, I confused it with the convolution stuff without thinking, it equals to $\partial^n f(x/\epsilon)/\epsilon^n$, what's the general idea?

Comment: Thus $\sup |\partial^k f_\epsilon| = \epsilon^{-k} \sup |\partial^k f|$ and higher order derivatives grow faster than lower order derivatives. Assume that $\partial^N f(x) = C \sum_{k=1}^{N} \sup |\partial^k f|$. What will be then $\sup |\epsilon^{N} \partial^k f_\epsilon|$? What happens in the cases $k<N$, $k=N$ and $k>N$ when $\epsilon \to 0$?

Comment: @md2perpe Somehow I still don't know... $\sup |\partial^k f_{\epsilon}|$ will vary as $\epsilon$ varies hence I don't know how to deal with it...

Comment: How will $\epsilon^{j} \partial^k f_\epsilon$ vary for $j<k$, $j=k$ and $j>k$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $N \in \mathbb N_0$, $C>0$, $x\in \mathbb R$ be given. W.l.o.g. we can assume that $x=0$.

Take $f \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ such that $\partial^{N+1}f(0) \neq 0$ and set $f_\epsilon(x) = \epsilon^N f(x/\epsilon).$ Then $\partial^k f_\epsilon(x) = \epsilon^{N-k} \partial^k f(x/\epsilon).$ Now,
$$
\sup |\partial^k f_\epsilon(x)| \to
\begin{cases}
0, & (k<N) \\
\sup |\partial^N f|, & (k=N) \\
\infty, & (k>N) \\
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore, $C \sum_{k=0}^{N} \sup |\partial^k f_\epsilon| \to C \sup |\partial^N f|$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, while $|\partial^{N+1} f_\epsilon(0)| \to \infty$. Thus, for $\epsilon$ small enough, 
$$
|\partial^{N+1} f_\epsilon(0)| > C \sum_{k=0}^{N} \sup |\partial^k f_\epsilon|
.
$$